# Windows Forms Application - Slow/Unresponsive UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# WinForm Application - UI Hangs during Long-Running Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216791/c-sharp-winform-application-ui-hangs-during-long-running-operation)

I created a Windows Form Application using C# and .NET Framework 4.0. I'm having a problem where while the program is doing work I can't move around the window and if I minimize it I can't get it to come back. I assume this is because I'm doing work on the same thread that the UI is running on.

Could this be the cause? If so how do I fix it?

Comment: It depends on what the work is. But you can try using the [Background Worker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: @MarkHall It's mostly uploading files to a server

Comment: I feel like this question is asked daily... can we start closing these out properly as duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to get into the internals of threads and threading, I would recommend using the BackgroundWorker control to do your task. The Background worker control encapsulates a lot of threading stuff behind the scenes to give you a clean programming interface.

The following link might help you (written by me)

[Correct way to use the BackgroundWorker](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=680130&highlight=backgroundworker)

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your code in:

```
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
            {
                //your code goes here
            }));
```

Because without tasks your code and UI runs on same thread it causes slow downs

Comment: Should I be using Tasks or the BackgroundWorker class?

Comment: @StickFigs See this MSDN Forum [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/75bb20d8-a3a0-4500-b03f-c81ce6bd4f31) Essentially if you need to update the UI use Background Worker otherwise use the System.Threading Namespace

Comment: I had the same problem in WPF and solved it using Tasks. I have never used BackroundWorker so I can't really advice on that. But I updated UI elements using Dispathcer.Invoke(). But I don't know if it is proper way