# How to prevent windows form from "hang"?

Tags: c#, winforms, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# WinForm Application - UI Hangs during Long-Running Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216791/c-sharp-winform-application-ui-hangs-during-long-running-operation)

I've created a progress bar example application in C# Windows Forms.

My application runs well but when I tried to move my application position or minimize, it gets "hang" until it's process not complied.

Please help: how to prevent my application from "hang"?

**This is my application code:**

```
public partial class ProgressBar : Form
{
    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value;
        for (value = 0; value != 10000000; value++)
            progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1;

        MessageBox.Show("ProgressBar Full", "Done", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ProgressBar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 10000000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Background Worker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the `ProgressBar`. Could you show us some code of your application?

Answer (score 4):

The reason its 'hanging'is because the processes are running in the same thread.
Move the progress bars process to another thread using a BackgroundWorker.

To prevent copy + paste, refer to the following links:

- [Background Worker Tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c#/)
- [Background Worker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to prevent this would be to delegate the workload to another thread.

There are several classes you can use to do so:

- [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)
- [Threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)
- [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

Background worker may be the simplest approach as it provides means to return the result to the UI thread. With other options you would need to *send* the result to the correct thread.