# Infinite For Loop Crash

Tags: c#, winforms

Here I Have a windows app with two items:

RichTextBox chatbot

Button startButton

Okay, so when the start button is pressed some code runs and then it hits this loop:

```
for (buf = input.ReadLine(); ; buf = input.ReadLine())
{

    //Display received irc message
    chatbox.Text += "\n " + buf;

    //Send pong reply to any ping messages
    if (buf.StartsWith("PING ")) { output.Write(buf.Replace("PING", "PONG") + "\r\n"); output.Flush(); }
    if (buf[0] != ':') continue;

    /* IRC commands come in one of these formats:
     * :NICK!USER@HOST COMMAND ARGS ... :DATA\r\n
     * :SERVER COMAND ARGS ... :DATA\r\n
     */
}
```

Boom... Program stopped responding...

When I run this code in a console program though it all works perf. Runs good, executes good, performs as expected.

What is this code apart of (Twitch Bot I am making)

Comment: The for loop needs to know under what condition to stop looping. Think about it, what would the equivalent while loop to this be?

Comment: Without sharing the actual Exception and Stack Trace, it will be very difficult to pinpoint the cause of your issues.

Comment: Use BackgroundWorker for long running operation in background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216791/winform-application-ui-hangs-during-long-running-operation

Comment: @WiXXeY Works perf. If you want, You can write that as a answer, get the cred

Comment: Winforms apps work differently to console apps. Winform apps are supposed to be "event driven", which means most of the time they are just spinning waiting for a message that tells them a button was clicked or whatever. If they go too long without checking for messages, Windows assumes they've frozen ("Program is not responding"). That's why you shouldn't have infinite loops in a button handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use a BackgroundWorker to avoid the UI stucking.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender,            System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     // Your infinite loop here, example is given below
     for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not necessarily good advice.  The original code appears to set the `Text` of a control, which is something that should absolutely not be done in the `DoWork` event handler.  If you do want to update the UI, make sure to call `ReportProgress` and perform the actual update in the `ProgressChanged` event handler.  That way, you keep all UI access to the UI thread.