# Does the program is still processing while "Not Responding"?

Tags: winforms

I have an Winforms Desktop Application, which make some big data processing which take some time. When I click somewhere on my app interface, the "Not Responding" windows pop up.
My question is, when i click "Wait for the program to respond", does the program is still working on processing data?

Comment: Yes. The UI is frozen because it cannot process further mouse/keyboard input, but the program is still processing your data, only after it finishes processing the data, it become responsive again and can process mouse/keyboard input.

Comment: So i should just leave it to finish the data processing and everything will be ok. Thank you.

Comment: probably a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216791/

Comment: Learn how to keep your UI responsive even it is processing big data in the background. :) This is a very fundamental skill for every Windows developer.

Comment: Yes I use on my apps background workers, threads, etc. but I just had a use case and want to know it :)