# How to make a real-time C# timer to show the execution time in Label without drop any Timer.Interval event?

Tags: c#

I have a button to start the Timer1, the Timer1 will print the current execution time every 100ms, but when I do something calculation, the timer1_Tick() will be paused until finished that calculation, I think the calculation bother the Timer1 so that timer1_Tick() is dropped(or blocked this thread).

In fact, the calculation is very complex, maybe take 40 seconds, I just need to show the execution time every 100ms to tell user how close to the end of this function, would you please tell me how to do this work??

```
    double a = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 100;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        a += 0.1;
        label1.Text = a.ToString();
    }

    private void UserStartTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = 0.0;
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void UserCalcSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            {
                s = i + j;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UserStopTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForm Application UI Hangs during Long-Running Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216791/winform-application-ui-hangs-during-long-running-operation)

Comment: Thx for your reply. but in fact, the Long-Running Operation in my case contain lots of "thread.sleep(random)" and "update label/button/chart", not just loop of loop, so even I add Application.DoEvent(), the priority of "thread.sleep(random)" is still higher than Timer-object

Comment: There is no real-time on a non real-time operating system. The timers are **not** accurate and the meaning of an interval set to 100 is *Well, after 100 milliseconds **or more** the Tick event will be signaled*

Answer (score 1):

Just execute the calculation in another thread or task:

```
private void UserCalcSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
       double s = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
           {
               s = i + j;
           }
       }
    }
}
```